# how to delete a line in file routes.rb ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my file routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :albums, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy]
    resources :conversation_replies, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy]
    resources :authors, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy]
  end
```

Now, I want delete line "resources :authors, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy]" by code in ruby on rails

please help me. thank you very much

Comment: Step 1: Load your editor. Step 2: Examine the editor's help system to see how to delete a line. Step 3: Go to the offending line. Step 4: Delete the line.

Answer (score 3):

It's a text file. It's not generated programmatically, it's meant to be edited by hand. You just delete the line. Open your editor, select the line, and hit the backspace or delete key.

Comment: i want edit this file by code ruby on rails, not edit by IDE. thanks

Comment: That isn't how Rails works. You can't edit this file through Rails, you edit it by hand. Rails provides *no* support for doing this. Attempting to edit your routes file from within a running Rails application isn't going to do anything for you, as the application needs to be restarted to detect the changes. If you really want to do this, it's a Ruby problem, and you're really just asking how to delete an arbitrary line from an arbitrary file. That has nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: I can add a line to routes file. but I do not restart sever, It's still running normally. my project is ruby on rails with database is MongoDB. Sorry, my English is not good

Comment: This might work in development mode, but that's only meant to make it easier to *type* new routes into your `routes.rb`. You are not meant to programmatically alter that file at run time.

Comment: in mongodb, i can create, update, delete model, controller, view, routes without rails restart

Comment: Changing `routes.rb` by code will not work in production unless you restart the server after every change. It is bad design.